# Configuring graphqlServlet with Jetty Server

Tags: kotlin, graphql-java

Getting below compilation error while adding servlet mapping. Not Sure what is wrong with below code while adding graphqlServlet to handler.
`Compilation error-` None of the following functions can be called
with the arguments supplied.

> (Servlet!) defined in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder
> (Class<out Servlet!>!) defined in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder
> (Source!) defined in org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder

GraphQLServlet.kt

```
class GraphQLServlet(schemaBuilder: SchemaBuilder) : SimpleGraphQLHttpServlet() {
    private val schema = schemaBuilder.buildSchema()
    public override fun doPost(request: HttpServletRequest?, response: HttpServletResponse?) {
        super.doPost(request, response)
    }
    public override fun getConfiguration(): GraphQLConfiguration {
        return GraphQLConfiguration.with(schema)
            .with(GraphQLQueryInvoker.newBuilder().build())
            .build()
    }
}
```

Jetty.kt

```
class API {            
    fun start() {
        val handler = createHandler()
        Server(8080).apply {
            setHandler(handler)
            start()
        }
    }
    private fun createHandler(): WebAppContext {
        val schemaBuilder = MyApiSchemaBuilder();
        val graphqlServlet : Servlet =GraphQLServlet(schemaBuilder)
        val handler = ServletHandler()
        return WebAppContext().apply {
            setResourceBase("/")
            handler.addServletWithMapping(ServletHolder(graphqlServlet), "/graphql")
        }
    }
}
```

> handler.addServletWithMapping(ServletHolder(graphqlServlet),
> "/graphql")

Answer (score 0):

I am able to figure out. i have added jetty-servlet in my dependency which solved my purpose